# Scala Macro annotations and IntelliJ code completion

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-macros

I'm using `Scala 2.10.3` and macro annotations in macro paradise to generate extra methods in an object. I'm also using `IntelliJ 13.0.2` with the Scala Plugin. Unsurprisingly the automatic code completion doesn't find the extra methods added by the macro annotation on the target object. Is there a way to make this work? I'm no expert on IntelliJ code completion but I'm thinking I need IntelliJ to pick up the compiled version of the target object, not the source.
Could I structure my project differently such that the target object is in a different compilation unit?

Comment: Related question (slightly more detailed): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047492/

Comment: See the answer I've given there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33415719/9204